# Relative file path for Rcpp::sourceCpp

Tags: r, rcpp, testthat

How can I call `Rcpp::sourceCpp` with a relative path to a C++ file rather than an absolute path? `R CMD check` and `testthat` both work when I call `Rcpp:sourceCpp` with an absolute path:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("/home/jeff/MiniMiniMaxUQ/src/MiniMiniMaxUQ.cpp")
```

But when I try using `system.path` or a relative path like

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("../src/MiniMiniMaxUQ.cpp")
```

my package doesn't pass `R CMD check` because the C++ source file isn't found. It seems like there must be a standard way to do this kind of thing, but I don't know it. I'd greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: You should not be using `sourceCpp()` in a package in the first place as @Kevin hinted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `sourceCpp` here for a `.cpp` file already in `src/`? Why not explicitly use `.Call` to call the compiled code (which will be available for your tests)?

If you really want to dynamically call `sourceCpp` you can look at the test infrastructure in `Rcpp`: https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests

The `.cpp` files in the `cpp/` are `Rcpp::sourceCpp`ed, and the exposed functions are used to run the tests in the `runit.*` files.

But note that these are separate `.cpp` files (ie, they're in the `inst/` subdirectory, not the `src/` folder)